# Algorithm for matching ingredients to recipes in AS3 (High Level)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

This is a high level question; I don't want you to post any code or examples, but rather just roughly list how I would achieve what I want to do programatically - Please do not delete this question as the question I am posing requires real answers and is therefore on topic.

I am looking to build a very simple app for a university project in ActionScript 3.0 in Flash CS5.5. The app I envisage is much like Epicurious (http://www.epicurious.com/services/mobile). Basic functionality of the app is that you tell it what ingredients you have in your fridge, and it tells you all of the possible recipes that you can make with the ingredients you have listed.

I know how I would go about building the basic aspects of the app like the DataGrid holding the ingredients + the SharedObject to save the ingredients, but I don't know where to start with the "matching ingredients to recipes" part of the app - I know that I would have to store all of the ingredients in an array, but what would be the algorithm to match the ingredients to ingredients found in the recipes (Let's say for the purposes of the app, we have only a few recipes, maximum 20 recipes)

Just a note: I am a complete novice at AS3, but have experience in other programming languages like Java and VB.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each recipe in your recipe list, run through its ingredients, compare with what you have in the fridge. If not enough, next recipe. If everything is available, okay display this recipe.